# Password In Terminal

Tags: command-line

When I open terminal I see this

`lou@lou-dell-dxp051:~$`   ( Lou is the name of the PC)

and I see this in the tidal bar and on the first line. I'm not sure if this is what I should be seeing however I type a command anyway and I get asked for a password I don't no what it is? It won't even let me type until i hit enter 3 times and get 3 incorrect password attempts how can I fix this?thanks

Comment: what is the command?

Comment: The command probably has `sudo` in it. That's used to run commands with admin privileges. If you are an admin user your sudo password is same as your user password. Check output of `group` command. If you aren't in the sudo group, contact your admin for sudo access

Answer (score 0):

`lou-dell-dxp051` is the device name, you can change it by going to System Setting --> Details. In there, you can see Device Name with your name on it. You can change that name to whatever you want then press Enter. You must log out and login again to make it works.

I'm not sure what command you typed in, but if it asks you for password, it's the same password that you're using to login. Note that when you're typing your password on terminal, your password will not present on terminal but keep typing and then hit Enter.